# Target every 3rd and 1st item from list using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to click on every 3rd and 1st item from list. I want to show a alert by click on these elements. I have tried but its giving alert only by clicking on first element.

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.filters').on('click', 'ul li.active:nth-of-type(3n+1)', function(){
        alert('hi')
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work. Perhaps not all `li` elements have the `active` class and that's why only the first works?

If so, try:

```
$('.filters').on('click', 'ul li:nth-of-type(3n+1)', function(){
    alert('hi')
}
```

Comment: :P oh you are right Sir Chris.. ow my code is working ... Sorry and thanks a lot for your help..

Comment: Glad I could assist :)

Answer (score 1):

Not all li items have active class. You should try this:

```
$(".filters").on('click', 'ul li:nth-of-type(3n+1)', function(){
  alert("hi");
}
```